# Create [hostgator] tag?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I see there is a [dreamhost] tag. That's useful: I like to see what issues of [mediawiki] users are host-specific, because certain shared hosts can be quite painful.

I notice there are [200 questions mentioning HostGator](https://serverfault.com/search?q=hostgator) and quite a few of them look specific to that host (or if not, they should be edited to reflect they aren't). Would it be useful to add them a [hostgator] tag?

Presumably there are other shared hosting services in similar conditions.

Comment: While I can see some practical interest in this notion, I think ServerFault in general, as a community, is loathe to make it easier for those using shared hosting to litter the site with questions about why their web app isn't working. Questions involving web hosting control panels are off topic anyway, so I think a vast majority of questions that would be specific enough to [tag:godaddy] for example would be closed anyway.

Comment: @Wesley makes sense and indeed I'm surprised to see several open ones, however as long as they're present I'd like them to be tidy. :)

Comment: Broken windows, etc.

Comment: Oh and don't sweat the downvotes. On meta sites it just means "disagree with the idea" not "u suk loser"

Comment: @Wesley thanks for the note. I know from other SE metas, I wasn't offended. ;)

Comment: I think it would be preferable to get rid of [tag:dreamhost]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shared hosting isn't on topic here anyway, so questions about it should just be cleaned up and closed.

For the few people who might have a VPS or dedicated server from Hostgator, it's a bit less clear-cut.

I won't complain if such a tag suddenly appears, as I do generally advise people to name their service providers for a variety of reasons, and such tags also make it easier for those providers to support their customers here (if they choose to do so).

But I don't think we need to go too far out of our way to create the tag, either.

In the end, if you want to close questions that should be closed, and retag the rest, that ought to be fine.